# Expo logs not showing on my console (react native)

Tags: react-native

Hi im having a problem with showing my expo logs... my terminal is showing

"Starting project at C:\xampp\htdocs\AwesomeProject
Starting Metro Bundler
Waiting on http://localhost:8081
Logs for your project will appear below."

and it's been hours

I tried adding this

"import { Logs } from 'expo';

Logs.enableExpoCliLogging()" (got it on the internet)

on App.js file and still not working